# Matching the word without space and has to include certain start of the word

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to match

driver. in

```
def fun
    driver.find_element(:link_text, "Standard Menu Rates").click
    driver.find_element(:id, "jpform:fromStation").send_keys("HOSUR - HSRA")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "jpform:toStation").send_keys("SATUR - SRT")
```

So I have to written the following regular expression

```
^driver.
```

But driver. is having some space infront of the word, so it's not matching, How would I eliminate the space as well as stick to the start of the string as driver not @driver or not any other word?

Input

```
def fun
    driver.find_element(:link_text, "Standard Menu Rates").click
    driver.find_element(:id, "jpform:fromStation").send_keys("HOSUR - HSRA")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "jpform:toStation").send_keys("SATUR - SRT")
```

output

```
    driver.find_element(:link_text, "Standard Menu Rates").click
    driver.find_element(:id, "jpform:fromStation").send_keys("HOSUR - HSRA")
```

And also,

I know to match those words inside the "" but how would I match those words which are outside the double quote?

Input

```
# 0 = {String@3546} "Policy Duration (Days)"
# 1 = {String@3547} "Related Proposal Nr."
```

Ouput

```
# 0 = {String@3546} 
# 1 = {String@3547}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments, you want to match the *start of the line*, then any number of whitespaces on the same line, then `driver` and then a dot.

You need to use `[[:blank:]]*` (it will match any 0+ Unicode horizontal whitesdace chars). Note also, the `.` should be escaped to match a literal `.`.

Use

```
/^[[:blank:]]*driver\./
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/iHY0XUKkMJ)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `[[:blank:]]*` - 0+ *horizontal* whitespace chars
- `driver` - a literal substring
- `\.` - a dot.

As for the second part, you may remove `"..."` substrings from the strings using

```
s.gsub(/[[:blank:]]*"[^"]*"$/, '')
```

See this [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/pASBSwZkkt)

Alternatively, if you want to *match* a *line part* up to the first `"`, you may use

```
/^[^"\r\n]+/
```

See [this Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/qp6WDTqaQT)

Comment: I am trying with the following string   `def execute
    driver.find_element(:id, "usernameId").send_keys("xxx")
    driver.find_element(:name, 'xxxx'` but it's not working.

Comment: By the way I have extended my question, I think you haven't looked at my second question, care to answer that as well?

Comment: @RAJ The "second" part is not related to the first part, it is not clear at all what you want to get, thus, it is off-topic. The first part is quite clear, and your effort shown is fine, you just need a little help with that.

Comment: For the first problem your given solution is not working for me, I have pasted code  `def execute driver.find_element(:id, "usernameId").send_keys("xxx") driver.find_element(:name, 'xxxx'`  If you try this with your regular expression, it's not working.

Comment: For the second one, I need to match the string which is outside the quote not inside for an example I need to match `something` while given the expression is `something "inside"` it needs to match `something`

Comment: You say *stick to the start of the string*: `\A` matches the start of  a string in a Ruby regex. `^` matches the start of a *line*. `\s` or `[[:space:]]` will work for you 100%. If you need to get rid of any substrings between `"`, you may use `s.gsub(/"[^"]*"/, "")`.

Comment: Your given expression is not working for me, Please place my string in the rubular and check it. But @marvel308 solution is working for me.

Comment: @RAJ So, you have a *multiline* string, and you want to match the start of the line, then one or more *horizontal* whitespaces, 0 or more, then `driver`? Then you need `/^[[:blank:]]*driver\./`.

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you please look at that?

Comment: Updated once again what's input and what' output, can you please look at that?

Comment: Your updated answer is not working for me, can you please look at my input and output section?

Comment: Well, you did not say those conditions must be combined. Perhaps, `^(?!\s*[^\w\s]driver\.)(?:\s*driver\.|[^"\r\n]*)` could help, but your question is too unclear and broad.

Comment: Hi, Yours is working fine, Actually I was typing in Rubymine search with regular expression and it was not working. Thanks, upvoted your answer.

Comment: @RAJ, FYI: marvel's regex contains unnecessary word boundary, `^\s*\bdriver\.` = `^\s*driver\.`, because between the optional whitespaces at the start and `d` letter the word boundary is implicit. Actually, I think my answer covers the whole scenario posted in the question, and even deals with Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the regex

```
^\s*\bdriver\.
```

where \b is represents a boundary. check the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/7h6tQh/1)

for the 2nd part, you can replace the string inside the quotes. The remaining string would be the required string see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/PVG4AS/1)

Comment: really? i don't know this, sorry

Comment: Yeah your given expression works fine for me, But can care to answer answer my second question as well?

Comment: Yours is matching what is within the quote, but I wanted to match what's outside the quote.

Comment: you can replace the matched part with an empty string. That way the string left would be the one without quotes

Comment: That's fine, but I am learning to use Regular expression so I checking any way to match this pattern which is outside the quote.

Comment: I don't understand why we still need to use \b because it works without using \b as well.

Comment: HI, If you have updated this answer `regex101.com/r/7h6tQh/1` I will accept your answer.